# Selenium python says textarea is not interactable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to simply insert text into a textarea on a page, nothing I have tried or found on the internet has worked. When I try to either click the element or send keys to it I get an error saying that the element is not interactable, a wait doesn't solve this since if I make an explicit wait to wait until it becomes interactable it just times out every time, meaning it never becomes interactable.

This is the html of the textarea I am trying to target:

```
<textarea _ngcontent-kjr-c428="" placeholder="Enter Description" name="description" maxlength="120" required="" class="input-text ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched"></textarea>
```

I did also try sending text in there with javascript, but didn't manage to succeed, simply nothing happened.
Any help is appreciated since I am truly and utterly stuck

my code:

```
descriptionInput = wait.until(presence((By.NAME, 'description')))
    descriptionInput.click()
    descriptionInput.send_keys("Test")
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: oh okay sorry @JaSON I didn't think it'd be of much importance in this situation, but I added it.

Comment: Code is the most important thing. Can't fix what we can't see. That said don't you need to call the driver? Something like `driver.descriptionInput.send_keys("Test")`

Comment: Note that `@name` might be not unique. Check if there are more than 1 textarea with `name="description"`

Comment: As you are getting element not interactable, its look like its not an issue of element identification. Also you have mentioned all possible remedies but scrolling to element ( In  case its not in window frame). Can you try to scroll to element before you use sent text. 
*driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", descriptionInput)*

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, as @JaSON pointed out, that there were indeed more elements named description